# Mac OSX Firefox 4 - flash is very slow

Tags: flash, apache-flex, macos, firefox, adobe

Has anyone else found that flash is VERY slow when using Firefox 4 on Mac OS X?

This happens when the .swf gets larger than ~1000px, the whole .swf is slow to scroll, respond, etc.

Has anyone else noticed this and figured out something to enhance speed?

Thanks!

Comment: What particular version of the flash player plugin are you using, can you give a detailed breakdown of your specs and versions of all used, possibly running top in the terminal to see if it gives any insight.  Debugging with the Flash Profiler can help you to find memory leaks or CPU killer method that are occurring.  I have no Mac to test although I suppose I should pony up the coin for a mac mini for testing, I just despise Apple too much and work for a pure PC user base... guess e-bay is in my future :).  Do you experience the same with Safari or other browsers or just firefox?

Comment: Man the prices on eBay are even ridiculous, what gives Mac users? when will you stop dumping money on cheap hardware, just because it has a shiny aluminum case doesn't mean they spent any more on your processor or ports... anyhow enough ranting, here's a bit of goodness I found on the topic: http://blog.kaourantin.net/?s=mac this looks like some good reading http://blog.kaourantin.net/

Comment: This isn't an issue with our application that I am explaining in terms of general speed. Sure, our .swf is not as optimal as it could be, but it is unbearably slow in Mac OSX Firefox 4, and only that browser. Chrome, IE, Safari, Firefox 4/PC, etc all work fine...

Comment: Reading through the most recent change logs for the beta release notes I found this bug that appears to be highly correlated... like I was saying the particular build is probably going to make a difference here as it appears there's been quite a bit changing recently with regard to how plugins are handled in Firefox (separating the process etc.) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591687 have you tried variations of the 4 beta versions perhaps you'll have more luck with newer releases.

Comment: I haven't tried variations of 4. 4 is out of beta, do we have access to nightly builds of 4.x or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always noticed Flash to be slower on Macs than any other OS. I believe it has something to do with the lock that Macs have on any application, but it could also be because you're using wmode='transparent' or there's a lot of bad performing code in your application.

Comment: Ya it's always been much faster in other OS's, but it's atleast been acceptable. Firefox 4/Mac is unacceptable for my site...

Comment: But works fine in chrome?  Could it be that you're using the debug playing in firefox? Do you have a lot of logging?  How about how you compile the app? is it in debug mode or release?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in Chrome. I am using it via exporting a release build. Not using the debug player - odd.

Comment: debug builds are slower than release builds because of the extra metadata and logging.  I would also check your cpu usage when you application runs (check for plugin-container). It could be that Firefox has a particular bug.  Have you tried with Firefox 3 instead of 4?

Comment: Yes, works fine in firefox 3. The only browser I have any issues in at all is Firefox 4/Mac...

Comment: Yeah, it's probably Firefox 4's new plugin sandboxing.  I wouldn't worry about it right now since the fix for it should be out soon :)

Comment: Hey @andrewpthorp I also tried this out at home (on a quad-core 2.6GHz PC) and found it to be running slow in Firefox (3.6.10 hadn't upgraded yet), after thinking about it for a second realized that Chrome handles it's own FP plugin internally, IE uses the ActiveX one and I have the debug FP installed.  After installing the non-debug player in FF it worked out much smoother, wonder if this is partially what you're suffering from.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're doing in the SWF, but seeing as your problem is happening when the SWF gets bigger than 1000px, it's probably drawing a crap ton of vectors. If you have a link to the SWF in question, it'd be easier to figure out.

Also, as J_A_X mentioned, it's only recently that Macs have allowed Flash Player access to hardware acceleration

Comment: I hear ya, but it's just odd that it is painfully slow in Firefox 4/Mac, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same problem and ONLY in firefox4 OSX. We managed to get a significant speed boost by removing the page css which was scaling a background image beyond the window constraints - my guess is this process is handed off to the GPU by webkit but not so much in firefox. i'd suggest looking carefully at any 100%+ values in the css...

This even made youtube embeds on the page play smoother.